# Logarithmic jQuery Boostrap slider with ticks

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-slider

I am trying to create logarithm slider as given on this website
https://www.enplug.com/pricing?plan=annual&displays=5&devices=5
I am to achieve some success here, but not able to match ticks, here is my HTML/JS code.
I am using jQuery [bootstrap slider](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider)

Complete code snippet here

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

            

           //  Without JQuery
            var slider = new Slider('#ex15', {
                min: 1,
                max: 1000,
                scale: 'logarithmic',
                value:1,
                step: 1,
                
            });
            $("#ex15").on("slide", function (slideEvt) {
                $(".ex15SliderVal").val(slideEvt.value);
                $(".tick-text").each(function (data, index) {
                    $(this).attr("selected", false);
                })

               
            });

            $(".ex15SliderVal").bind('keyup change click input', function () {
                var GetValue = $(this).val();
               
                slider.setValue(GetValue);

             
            });
           

            $(".tick-text").on('click', function () {
                var GetValue = $(this).attr('data-id');
                var Item = $(this);
              
                slider.setValue(GetValue);
                $(".ex15SliderVal").val(GetValue);
                $(".tick-text").each(function (data,index) {
                    $(this).attr("selected",false);
                    })
                Item.attr("selected", true);


                
            })
            
        });
```

```css
 .w-container {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            max-width: 940px;
        }

        .calculator-form {
            font-family: 'Raleway';
        }

            .calculator-form section.pricing-container .header {
                margin: 0 0 12px;
                text-align: left;
                font-size: 26px;
                line-height: 1;
                font-weight: 400;
                color: #1d242c;
            }

            .calculator-form section.pricing-container .description {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                text-align: left;
                font-size: 14px;
                line-height: 17px;
                color: #53595e;
            }

        .slider-track {
            background-image: none;
            background-image: none;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            filter: none;
            -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
            border-radius: 4px;
            /*Hide the default slider*/
            display: none !important;
        }

        .calculator-form section.pricing-container {
            padding: 18px 30px;
            border: 1px solid #d3dbe2;
            background-color: #fafafa;
        }

            .calculator-form section.pricing-container .form-columns {
                display: -moz-flex;
                display: -ms-flexbox;
                display: flex;
                -ms-flex-pack: justify;
                -moz-justify-content: space-between;
                justify-content: space-between;
            }

                .calculator-form section.pricing-container .form-columns .left-column {
                    width: 255px;
                    margin-right: 45px;
                }

                .calculator-form section.pricing-container .form-columns .right-column {
                    display: flex;
                    justify-content: flex-end;
                    flex-grow: 1;
                    align-items: center;
                }

            .calculator-form section.pricing-container .number-input {
                width: 76px;
                height: 40px;
                padding-left: 0;
                padding-right: 0;
                border: 1px solid #d3dbe2;
                border-radius: 3px;
                text-align: center;
                color: #396ebc;
                font-family: Roboto;
                font-size: 24px;
                font-weight: 400;
                -moz-appearance: textfield;
            }

            .calculator-form section.pricing-container .display-slider {
                flex-grow: 1;
                position: relative;
                margin-right: 0;
                margin-left: 25px;
            }

                .calculator-form section.pricing-container .display-slider .ticks-container, .slider.slider-horizontal .slider-tick-label-container {
                    display: -ms-flexbox;
                    display: flex;
                    -ms-flex-direction: row;
                    flex-direction: row;
                    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
                    justify-content: space-between;
                    padding-bottom: 13px;
                    padding-top: 8px;
                    margin-left: -3px;
                }

                    .calculator-form section.pricing-container .display-slider .ticks-container .tick-text {
                        color: #1d242c;
                        font-size: 14px;
                        font-weight: 400;
                        font-family: Roboto;
                        cursor: pointer;
                    }

                    .calculator-form section.pricing-container .display-slider .ticks-container .tick-dot {
                        font-size: 12px;
                        margin-top: -1px;
                    }

                    .calculator-form section.pricing-container .display-slider .ticks-container .tick-text:hover {
                        opacity: .75;
                        color: #356bba;
                    }

                    .calculator-form section.pricing-container .display-slider .ticks-container .tick-text[selected=true], .tick-text[selected=selected] {
                        color: #356bba !important;
                    }

                .calculator-form section.pricing-container .display-slider .toggle, .slider-handle {
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 24px;
                    height: 24px;
                    border-radius: 16px;
                    background-color: #356bba;
                    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
                    cursor: pointer;
                    /*top: 30px;*/
                    top: -11px;
                }

        .slider.slider-horizontal {
            width: 100%;
            height: 32px;
        }

            .calculator-form section.pricing-container .display-slider .track, .slider.slider-horizontal .slider-track {
                display: -moz-flex;
                display: -ms-flexbox;
                display: flex;
                -moz-flex-direction: row;
                -ms-flex-direction: row;
                flex-direction: row;
                width: 100%;
                height: 2px;
                background-color: #d3dbe2;
                margin-bottom: 12px;
                -ms-flex-pack: justify;
                -moz-justify-content: space-between;
                justify-content: space-between;
            }

        .hide {
            display: none;
        }

        .calculator-form section.pricing-container .display-slider .track .tick {
            margin-top: -2px;
            width: 2px;
            height: 6px;
            background-color: #d3dbe2;
        }

        .calculator-form section .pricing-card.selectable[selected=selected] {
            border-width: 4px;
            border-color: #4468b8;
            color: #4468b8;
        }

        .calculator-form section .pricing-card.selectable {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .calculator-form section .pricing-card {
            align-self: flex-start;
            width: 276px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            padding: 4px 6px 6px;
            background: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #d3dae1;
            border-radius: 3px;
            color: #333941;
        }
            .calculator-form section .pricing-card.selectable:not([selected=selected]) {
                padding-bottom: 0;
                color: #777b7f;
            }
            .calculator-form section .pricing-card.selectable:not([selected=selected]) .pricing-card-content {
                margin: 3px;
            }

        .calculator-form section .pricing-card-content {
            padding: 12px 10px;
            line-height: 1;
        }

        .calculator-form section .pricing-card.selectable:not([selected=selected]) .pricing-card-hint {
            display: none;
        }

        .calculator-form section .pricing-card-hint.special-offer--colored-text {
            color: #6ec84d;
        }

        .calculator-form section .pricing-card-hint.special-offer {
            background: #eff9ed;
            border-color: #c0e8b3;
        }

        .calculator-form section .pricing-card-hint {
            padding: 4px 9px 3px;
            text-align: right;
            font-size: 13px;
            font-weight: 500;
            background: #eaeff8;
            border: 1px solid #adbfe1;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }

        .calculator-form section .pricing-card-header {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            font-size: 26px;
            line-height: 1;
            text-align: left;
        }

        .calculator-form section .pricing-card-description {
            font-size: 16px;
            text-align: right;
        }

            .calculator-form section .pricing-card-description .rate-summary {
                font-family: Roboto;
                font-size: 22px;
                font-weight: 500;
            }

            .calculator-form section .pricing-card-description .monthly-price {
                margin-bottom: -2px;
            }

            .calculator-form section .pricing-card-description .rate-hint {
                font-size: 14px;
                margin-top: 3px;
            }


            .calculator-form section .pricing-card-description .license-count strong {
                margin: 0 7px 0 10px;
            }

            .calculator-form section .pricing-card-description strong {
                font-family: Roboto;
                font-size: 32px;
                font-weight: 500;
            }

            .calculator-form section .pricing-card-description .license-count {
                margin-top: 6px;
            }

        .calculator-form section .pricing-card-description {
            font-size: 16px;
            text-align: right;
        }

        .calculator-form section .pricing-card-hint.special-offer--colored-text {
            color: #6ec84d;
        }

        .calculator-form section .pricing-card-hint.special-offer {
            background: #eff9ed;
            border-color: #c0e8b3;
        }

        .calculator-form section .pricing-card-hint strong {
            font-family: Roboto;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: 500;
        }

        .calculator-form section .pricing-card-description strong {
            font-family: Roboto;
            font-size: 32px;
            font-weight: 500;
        }

        .calculator-form section .pricing-card-hint.special-offer {
            background: #eff9ed;
            border-color: #c0e8b3;
        }

        .calculator-form section .pricing-card-hint {
            padding: 4px 9px 3px;
            text-align: right;
            font-size: 13px;
            font-weight: 500;
            background: #eaeff8;
            border: 1px solid #adbfe1;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }
        .calculator-form section .pricing-card.selectable:not([selected=selected]) {
            padding-bottom: 0;
            color: #777b7f;
        }

        .calculator-form section .pricing-card + .pricing-card {
            margin-left: 26px;
        }

        .section-light {
            font-weight: 300;
        }

        .calculator-form section .pricing-card.selectable:not([selected=selected]) hr {
            border-top: 2px solid #979ca2;
        }

        .calculator-form section .pricing-card hr {
            margin: 13px 0 15px;
            border-top: 2px solid #333941;
        }

        .calculator-form section .pricing-container hr {
            height: 1px;
            border: none;
            border-top: 1px solid #d3dbe2;
            margin: 25px 0;
        }
        .calculator-form section .pricing-card.selectable[selected=selected] hr {
            border-top: 2px solid #4468b8;
        }

        .calculator-form section .pricing-card.selectable:not([selected=selected]):hover {
            box-shadow: 0 0 11px rgba(33,33,33,.2);
        }
        @media (min-width: 769px) {
            .mobile-only {
                display: none !important;
            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Pricing</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.0.2/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css">
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.0.2/bootstrap-slider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body >
    
  <div class="w-container">

    <div class="calculator-form">
        <section class="pricing-container">
            <div class="form-columns">
                <div class="left-column">
                    <div class="header">Software Licenses</div>
                    <p class="description desktop-only">
                        Use the slider to select the number of displays you want to use with Enplug software. You'll need one software license per display.
                    </p>
                   
                </div>
                <div class="right-column">
                    <input class="number-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-valid-min ex15SliderVal" type="number" min="1" value="1">
                    <div class="display-slider">
                        <div class="ticks-container">
                           

                             <div class="tick-text" data-display-count="1" data-id="1" selected="true">1</div>
                            <div class="tick-dot">●</div>
                            <div class="tick-text" data-display-count="2" data-id="2" selected="false">2</div>
                            <div class="tick-dot">●</div>
                            <div class="tick-text" data-display-count="5" data-id="5" selected="false">5</div>
                            <div class="tick-dot">●</div>
                            <div class="tick-text" data-display-count="10" data-id="10" selected="false">10</div>
                            <div class="tick-dot">●</div>
                            <div class="tick-text" data-display-count="30" data-id="30" selected="false">30</div>
                            <div class="tick-dot">●</div>
                            <div class="tick-text" data-display-count="100" data-id="100" selected="false">100</div>
                            <div class="tick-dot">●</div>
                            <div class="tick-text" data-display-count="250" data-id="250" selected="false">250</div>
                            <div class="tick-dot">●</div>
                            <div class="tick-text" data-display-count="1000" data-id="1000" selected="false">1,000</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="track">
                            <div class="tick"></div>
                              <input id="ex15" type="text" data-slider-min="1" data-slider-max="1000"  />
                            <div class="tick"></div>
                        </div>
                      
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="form-columns" ng-hide="isEnterpriseOffer()">
                <div class="left-column">
                    <div class="header">Plan Type</div>
                </div>
                <div class="right-column">
                    <div class="pricing-card selectable" ng-selected="isAnnualPlanSelected" ng-click="setPlanType('annual')" selected="selected">
                        <div class="pricing-card-content">
                            <div class="pricing-card-header">Annual Plan</div>
                            <div class="pricing-card-description">
                                <div class="monthly-price">
                                    <strong class="ng-binding">$54.00</strong>/month
                                    <span class="mobile-only">per License</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="rate-hint desktop-only">
                                    Per License
                                </div>
                                <div class="license-count">
                                    x<strong class="ng-binding">5</strong>License<span ng-show="pricingParams.displays !== 1">s</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="pricing-card-description">
                                <div class="rate-summary ng-binding">
                                    $3,240.00
                                </div>
                                <div class="rate-hint">
                                    Charged Annually
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pricing-card-hint special-offer special-offer--colored-text">
                            You are saving<br>
                            <strong class="ng-binding">$360.00</strong> /year
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pricing-card selectable" ng-selected="isMonthlyPlanSelected" ng-click="setPlanType('monthly')">
                        <div class="pricing-card-content">
                            <div class="pricing-card-header">Monthly Plan</div>
                            <div class="pricing-card-description">
                                <div class="monthly-price">
                                    <strong class="ng-binding">$60.00</strong>/month
                                    <span class="mobile-only">per License</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="rate-hint desktop-only">
                                    Per License
                                </div>
                                <div class="license-count">
                                    x<strong class="ng-binding">5</strong>License<span ng-show="pricingParams.displays !== 1">s</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="pricing-card-description">
                                <div class="rate-summary ng-binding">
                                    $300.00
                                </div>
                                <div class="rate-hint">
                                    Charged Monthly
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pricing-card-hint">
                            Upgrade to Annual Plan and save<br>
                            <strong class="ng-binding">$360.00</strong> /year
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </section>

       
    </div>
</div>

    
   

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to make it exact like shown in the above link https://www.enplug.com/pricing?plan=annual&displays=5&devices=5

Ticks part is not correct,slider position is 2, ticks number is 5.
I have read bootstrap-slider documentation but not able to achieve same layout.

Answer (score 1):

Are you support responsive design in that slider?
I just checked it in the jsfiddle, but the slider(the blue ball) position isn't correct at all.
It seems you set the **flex-grow: 1;**, but the class(slider-horizontal)'s width is fixed, so the div(ticks-container) width don't have the same width as it in the first place.

However, you may implement this way; that is using Bootstrap slider tick option.
That way, you don't need to worry kind of this issue, because basically, the plugin guaranteed to run correctly.
The labels position has some work(bottom→top), though.
[For Example](https://jsfiddle.net/vqg8rb2s/)

```
var mySlider = new Slider("#test-slider", {
    min: 1,
    max: 1000,
    step: 1,
    ticks: [0, 100, 200, 300, 500, 1000],
    ticks_labels: ["<a href='#test'>0</a>","100","200","300","500","1000"],
    ticks_positions: [0, 20, 40 , 60 , 80 , 100]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle link and above JS code, not exactly what I was looking for but it helped me.